# Convert Firebase RecycleView data to PDF using iText in android

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I'm developing an android app with cloud `Firestore`. In a particular activity, I'm using `RecyclerView` to display firestore data.

With the help of below code I'm able to generate `PDF` file with a single text, but unable to complete the code to get the firestore RecyclerView data in PDF. To do this what type of code I need to enter.

```
    private void createPdf() throws FileNotFoundException, DocumentException {

        File docsFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Documents");
        if (!docsFolder.exists()) {
            docsFolder.mkdir();
            Log.i(TAG, "Created a new directory for PDF");
        }

        pdfFile = new File(docsFolder.getAbsolutePath(),"HelloWorld.pdf");
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(pdfFile);
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, output);
        document.open();
        document.add(new Paragraph(mContentEditText.getText().toString()));
        document.close();
        previewPdf();
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean instead of         document.add(new Paragraph(mContentEditText.getText().toString()));
 use the data of each item in RecyclerView?

Comment: Yes. I want to save the RecyclerView data to PDF

Comment: You have to iterate through the adapter and use the method to add the data to the PDF.